# I ain't able to convert json in XML

Tags: json, xml, wso2

I am relative new in wso2 and are having some little problems. I already asked here, how to make this conversion, and was able to do so in another moment. But now i tried to do the same with the code passed for stack overflow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/Test" name="JsonToXmlApi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/xml/">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/xml"/>
            <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <send/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

And with the send equal request, of what was taught before:

[image]

But now i am receiving this error:

```
ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the response
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done.
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:555)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:371)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done.
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1522)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1551)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.doWriteStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:650)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:638)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:626)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:277)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.serialize(JsonDataSource.java:88)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
        ... 24 more
[2017-07-25 15:35:50,646] ERROR - Axis2Sender Accept:*/*,Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br,Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,Cache-Control:no-cache,Content-Type:application/soap+xml,Host:localhost:8280,Origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop,Postman-Token:89253418-6c05-c959-5e21-2ce7555e0cb6,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><location_response><name>cafe</name><tags>dsdsd</tags></location_response></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:613)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:266)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:325)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:371)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done.
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:555)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Can not output XML declaration, after other output has already been done.
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1522)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1551)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.doWriteStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:650)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:638)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:626)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeStartDocument(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:277)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonDataSource.serialize(JsonDataSource.java:88)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
        ... 24 more
```

I already searched in the internet and in stackoverflow, but none of the resolutions used to this problem, solved in my case.
If anyone could help me i would stay quite grateful.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: which version of ESB or API, do you use?

Comment: I tried with wso2 esb 5.0.0 and wso2ei 6.1.1. Both had the same wrongs.

Comment: Make sure the content-type is set properly and also check for any REST client issues. The sample API that you have posted here, should work fine.

Comment: The content-type is checked as asked, but i will check for some REST issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can get the response for your api without error. Try with "application/xml" in the api instead of "text/xml".

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Hello Rajjaz. Thank you from your help, i tried what you passed from me, but isn't work. With the link: 'http://localhost:8280/Test/xml' the wrong was the same and with 'http://localhost:8280/application/xml', i don't receive response, and the request was should in the cmd. I tried the two because i am unsure of the right way.

Comment: Hello Rajjaz. Thank you from your help, i found the resolution, my problem was that i changed the code of API and i forgot to check the artifacts. I now is a dump wrong, but sometimes i commit something like that now that i in the begin. Thank you from the patient.

Answer (score 0):

The API you have shared is working fine. I have tried with postman and advanced rest client.

Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/JSON+Support for more information about json support.
[image]